# Garbage characters in SqlDataReader.GetString() of converted TIMESTAMP

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sqlclient

I've got a SELECT that gets, among other things,

```
CONVERT(varchar(10), TIMESTAMP)
```

where TimeStamp is defined as

```
[TIMESTAMP] [binary](8) NULL
```

Some of the timestamps have bad data, meaning instead of something like **0x30332F31372F3131**, which converts to **"03/17/11"**, they have only the bottom four bytes, as in **0x0000000002F09ADD**.

When I do the SELECT in an MSSMS query window those bad ones come out blank, which is fine, but when I retrieve them in my program using an SqlDataReader the Strings for the bad timestamps come out with garbage characters, as in **`"    ðšÝ"`**.

Any ideas as to what I can do about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select case when ISDate(CONVERT(varchar(10), TIMESTAMP))=1 then CONVERT(varchar(10), TIMESTAMP) else null end
```